# Why does HashMap#containsKey take an parameter of type Object?

Tags: java

A coworker encountered a bug where HashMap#containsKey was used to verify if a key-value pair exists.  The specified key was a different type so the method would always return false.  For example (Let's assume the map is populated with objects that he wants to retrieve):

`Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

Long value = new Long(12);

boolean hasString = map.containsKey(value);`

My question is:

**Why does the Map implementation force you to put keys of type K and values of type V, but the containsKey() method allow you specify any object?**

There are other methods in the Map interface such as get() that also accept a parameter of type Object.

Comment: Also see http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html

Comment: Sorry about asking the duplicate question.  I tried to search around for it but I must have used the wrong keywords.  Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because Java's Map implementation uses the `.equals()` command to decide whether two objects are equal for the purposes of methods like `.containsKey()` or `.remove()`. And since `.equals()` compares with a general Object (and if you're overriding it,  you usually want a check at the top like `if (!(t instanceof T)) { return false; }` but there's no actual stipulation that A and B have to be the same type for `A.equals(B)` to be true.

Here's some code that highlights the difference. Might not do what you expect.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    static class Foo implements Comparable {
        public String a;

        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof Bar) { return a.equals((((Bar) obj).b)); }
            return false;
        }

        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            return this.equals(o) ? 0 : -1;
        }
    }

    static class Bar implements Comparable {
        public String b;

        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof Foo) { return b.equals((((Foo) obj).a)); }
            return false;
        }

        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            return this.equals(o) ? 0 : -1;
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Map<Foo, Bar> test = new TreeMap<Foo, Bar>();
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = new Bar();

        foo.a = "Hello";
        bar.b = "Hello";

        System.out.println(foo.equals(bar));
        System.out.println(bar.equals(foo));

        test.put(foo, bar);

        System.out.println(test.containsKey(bar));
        System.out.println(test.containsValue(foo));
    }

}
```